# Add column to existing multi-column index

Tags: mysql, indexing

In my table I have a multi-column index for the columns (name,folder)

I recently added a new column called date and I want to put an index into it, but I want to put it into the existing multi-column index

When I do `Alter table books add index theindex (date);`
I get `Duplicate key name 'theindex'`

How do I add another column to an index without creating a new key?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just change the syntax to the below way to add new columns to the index:

```
ALTER table `books` DROP INDEX theindex;
ALTER table `books` ADD INDEX theindex (`date`, `time`);
```

Be cautious about `FOREIGN KEYs`.  See, for example, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-online-ddl-operations.html

Comment: In older versions, it would be twice as fast to do both the `DROP` and `ADD` in the same `ALTER`.

Comment: If you don't need to preserve the index name and want to maintain query performance during the schema migration, consider adding a new multi-column index first, then dropping the old.

Comment: @RickJames and not in newer versions?

Comment: @ValerioBozz - I have not found a definitive answer to your question.